# Reading comma-separated words into pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file filled with words like so :

words.txt

```
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
"K", "L", "M", "N", "O"
```

How can I read this file using Pandas? My ultimate goal would be a series that contained (A, B, C, D, E. . .O)

read_csv seems geared towards a table.

I managed to accomplish this using

```
words = list(pd.read_csv('words.txt').columns)
```

But this is so ugly. I'm sure there's a better way.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a linebreak after `"E",`? If they are in separate lines, I don't think your solution works.

Comment: There isn't! Just wraps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need pandas library for this alone, you can simply use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module for this. Example -

```
import csv
with open('<csvfile>','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
    words = next(reader)
```

`skipinitialspace` is to skip the whitespace after the delimiter , which seems to be there in your csv.

---

Example/Demo -

My `a.csv` -

```
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"
```

Code and result -

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('a.csv','r') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
...     words = next(reader)
...
>>> words
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an answer

```
list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F", "G", "H", "I", "J","K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]

print(list)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
```

Comment: Hahahaha, made me chuckle! :) That was just an example, friend!

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to help the community back because I'm kind of new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure python you could do something like this to build a list:

```
words = [word.strip() for line in open("words.txt") for word in line.split(",") if word]
```